# "Round half up" on floating point values

Tags: sql-server, language-agnostic, floating-point, rounding

We are stuck with a database that (unfortunately) uses floats instead of decimal values. This makes rounding a bit difficult. Consider the following example (SQL Server T-SQL):

```
SELECT ROUND(6.925e0, 2)   --> returns 6.92
```

`ROUND` does [round half up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up), but since [floating point numbers cannot accurately represent decimal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), the "wrong" result (from the point of view of the end-user) is displayed. **I understand *why* this happens.**

I already came up with two possible solutions (both returning a float, which is, unfortunately, also a requirement):

1. Convert to a decimal data type before rounding: `SELECT CONVERT(float, ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(29,14), 6.925e0), 2))`
2. Multiply until the third digit is on the left-hand side of the decimal point (i.e. accurately represented), and then do the rounding: `SELECT ROUND(6.925e0 * 1000, -1) / 1000`

Which one should I choose? Is there some better solution? (Unfortunately, we cannot change the field types in the database due to some legacy applications accessing the same DB.)

**Is there a well-established *best practice* solution for this (common?) problem?**

(Obviously, the common technique "rounding twice" will not help here since 6.925 is already rounded to three decimal places -- as far as this is possible in a float.)

Comment: I tagged this both `sql-server` and `language-agnostic`, since the examples are in T-SQL but the question for a best-practice algorithm is a generic one.

Comment: There doesn't exist an algorithm or a function which can achieve what you want because most floats which are multiples of a base 10 fraction are not exactly representable. For instance, 6.925 is represented as a value slightly above or below, but never exact. Which way do you want it to be rounded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first solution seems safer, and also seems like a conceptually closer fit to the problem:  convert as soon as possible from float to decimal, do all relevant calculations within the decimal type, and then do a last minute conversion back to float before writing to the DB.

Edit:  You'll likely still need to do an extra round (e.g. to 3 decimal places, or whatever's appropriate for your application) immediately after retrieving the float value and converting to decimal, to make sure that you end up with the decimal value that was actually intended.  `6.925e0` converted to decimal would again be likely (assuming that the decimal format has > 16 digits of precision) to give something that's very close to, but not exactly equal to, `6.925`;  an extra round would take care of this.

The second solution doesn't look reliable to me:  what if the stored value for `6.925e0` happens to be, due to the usual binary floating-point issues, a tiny amount too small?  Then after multiplication by `1000`, the result *may* still be a touch under `6925`, so that the rounding step rounds down instead of up.  If you know your value always has at most 3 digits after the point, you could fix this by doing an extra round *after* multiplying by 1000, something like `ROUND(ROUND(x * 1000, 0), -1)`.

(Disclaimer:  while I have plenty of experience dealing with float and decimal issues in other contexts, I know next to nothing about SQL.)

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I am surprised that the normal practice is not mentioned here, so I just add it. 
Normally, you would add a small amount that you know is much smaller than the accuracy of the numbers you are working with, e.g. like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(6.925e0 + 1e-7, 2)
```

Of course the added amount must be larger than the precision of the floating point type that is used.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a really simple and effective solution. Thanks! Is this idea documented somewhere? (You mentioned that it is "normal practice"...)

Comment: Well, I don't know about documentation, but I have been using it for 25 years. The limitation, of course, is that you need to know the range of numbers you are working with. But in most practical situations, and certainly in rounding, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use an arbitrary-precision format such as DECIMAL. That way you can leave it to the language to get it right (or wrong as the case may be).

Comment: Obviously, yes. Unfortunately, as stated in the question, this is not an option.

Comment: Ah, ok, then I misunderstood your answer; I thought you were refering to changing the data type in the database. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to round the float column correctly using the following command:

SELECT CONVERT(float, ROUND(ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(38,14),float_column_name),3),2))