# calculating a percentage based on results from the query

Tags: sql-server, select, percentage

I currently run the query:

```
select table1.columnA as Barrier_1,
       table2.columnB as Action_1,
  from table2
  join table1 on table2.PrimKey = table1.PrimKey
 where table1.columnA is not null
   and table2.columnB is not null
 group by table1.columnA, table2.columnB
 order by table1.columnA
```

which returns the table:

```
Barrier_1   Action_1
____________________
   01     |    01
   01     |    02
   02     |    01
   02     |    03
   02     |    04
   03     |    02
   03     |    03
   04     |    01
   05     |    04
```

and what I want it to do is calculate the percentage of each action per barrier:

```
Barrier_1   Action_1   Percent_1
________________________________
   01     |    01    |   60%
   01     |    02    |   40%
   02     |    01    |   20%
   02     |    03    |   10%
   02     |    04    |   70%
   03     |    02    |   20%
   03     |    03    |   80%
   04     |    01    |  100%
   05     |    04    |  100%
```

Note that each action can show up multiple time per barrier.

So each barrier has it's own set of actions. For example, barrier one can have a total of 5 actions (2 being action 02 and 3 being action 01).

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `...percentage of each action per barrier`?

Comment: what formula do you use to calculate each line.  For example Barrier 05 with action 04.  Action 04 exists twice barrier 05 only once why is it 100% vs barrier 04 with action 01 (having 3 entries) at 100%?

Comment: So each barrier has it's own set of actions. For example, barrier one can have a total of 5 actions (2 being action 02 and 3 being action 01). Hopefully that answers both questions.

Comment: As the comments above say, you need to elaborate on the formula.  For example, barrier 01 has 2 values in the sample above... so why does 01/01 account for 60% while 01/02 accounts for 40%?  They each appear once so why isn't it 50%?  A SqlFiddle with some sample data would go a long way toward helping you.

Comment: I have them grouped if there are duplicates. There can be multiples for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query for getting sum of all `Actions` for one `Barrier`. And then calculate percentage of `Actions` for one `Barrier`.

```
SELECT b.ColumnA
, a.ColumnB
, ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,4),
                COUNT(a.ColumnB))* 100/
CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,4),
        (SELECT COUNT(ColumnB) FROM Action WHERE PrimKey=b.PrimKey))
, 2) AS Pros
FROM Action a
INNER JOIN Barrier b ON b.PrimKey=a.PrimKey
GROUP BY b.ColumnA, a.ColumnB, b.PrimKey
ORDER BY b.ColumnA
```

Here a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4841e/13) with data which I used for testing...

If your want to add a '%'-sign to result column, then you need to convert value of percentage to `VARCHAR` and add a sign.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @PercentageValue) + '%' AS PercentageValue
```

Comment: How will this work with my query though? I don't have a third table to use. It's just the Barriers table (table1) and the Actions table (table2) and I can't create a new one unless it's a temporary one. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @user1911612, I updated my answer for two tables. If my it's not working for you, please give some structure of your tables...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to conquer this.  Here is what I think is the most straight forward example:

```
SELECT table1.columnA as Barrier_1,
   table2.columnB as Action_1,
   ROUND(CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)
            /CAST(  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2 
                        WHERE t2.PrimKey = table1.PrimKey)
                    AS FLOAT)*100,2) AS Percent_1
  from table2
  join table1 on table2.PrimKey = table1.PrimKey
 where table1.columnA is not null
   and table2.columnB is not null
 group by table1.columnA, table2.columnB
 order by table1.columnA
```

If you want to add the percentage symbol you will have to convert to varchar at the end.

Note: I am converting to float type in the example, if you require a high degree of accuracy in the numbers, it is better to use a numeric/decimal type

Comment: This is similar to fabio's answer. This is what I had originally though except the subquery will return multiple values. I need it to be unique to the row it running the subquery for if that makes sense.

Comment: I assume your where clause and/or join clause is not exactly as in your example?  Or do i misunderstand?  The where clause on the subquery must be exactly as restrictive as the original query from that table.

Comment: @guitarultimate, I will not recomend using a ´FLOAT´ type if you going to ´ROUND´ a value of this type. ´FLOAT´ type are knowing of some problems with rounding: [“Round half up” on floating point values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370358/round-half-up-on-floating-point-values)

Comment: @Fabio your point is certainly valid. There are many inaccuracies with float type (not just rounding), but that does not mean it should never be used - it is a much smaller data type. The particular situation should dictate what to use, and I have warned in my answer.