# running a subquery based on the row it is returned in

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I currently run the query:

```
select table1.columnA as Barrier_1,
       table2.columnB as Action_1,
  from table2
  join table1 on table2.PrimKey = table1.PrimKey
 where table1.columnA is not null
   and table2.columnB is not null
 group by table1.columnA, table2.columnB
 order by table1.columnA
```

which returns the table:

```
Barrier_1   Action_1
____________________
   01     |    01
   01     |    02
   02     |    01
   02     |    03
   02     |    04
   03     |    02
   03     |    03
   04     |    01
   05     |    04
```

I want to also run a subquery which I am not sure how to do. I need to utilize both the barrier code and the action code to get a unique value from another table (tableC). So, for each row that I show above, there will be another field called "Desc" that gets returned from tableC:

```
Barrier_1   Action_1    Desc
______________________________
   01     |    01    |   15
   01     |    02    |   21
   02     |    01    |   17
   02     |    03    |   12
   02     |    04    |   19
   03     |    02    |   26
   03     |    03    |   13
   04     |    01    |   22
   05     |    04    |   14
```

Comment: What are the fields in TableC. If they have Barrier and Action fields you can add it to your join.

Comment: They do! Sorry I forgot to mention that. How would I do the join though?

Comment: !!! http://stackoverflow.com/q/16819768/1699210

Comment: two separate problems :-/

Comment: I know how to do a join, as I use it above. I guess I just don't know how to when there are multiple pieces to it.

Comment: You can have multiple `On` criteria. You just do another join to tablec on both criteria. Something like `Join TableC On Table1.ColumnA = TableC.Barrier_1 And Table2.ColumnB = TableC.Action_1`

Comment: yes, but I am not looking to join TableC in query. I need to do something more like 'join table1 on table1.columnA = tableC.Barrier_1' as well as 'join table2 on table2.columnB = tableC.Action_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the results of your barrier/action query to the table holding the desc field.

Basically there are two syntax options you can choose from.

You either put the barrier/action query on the bottom, which you could consider a 'nested query', Here is a sample of a nested query using the AdventureWorks sample database.

```
SELECT  C.ContactID
       ,C.EmployeeID
       ,D.[AddressID]
FROM    [HumanResources].[EmployeeAddress] D
INNER JOIN ( SELECT A.[ContactID]
                   ,B.EmployeeID
             FROM   [Person].[Contact] A
             INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] B
             ON     A.[ContactID] = B.[ContactID] ) C
ON      C.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID;
```

Or you put the barriers/action query on top, in what's know as a 'common table expression', and the previous sample in this syntax flavor would look like this:

```
WITH T1 ( ContactID, EmployeeID )
      AS ( SELECT   A.[ContactID]
                   ,B.EmployeeID
           FROM     [Person].[Contact] A
           INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] B
           ON       A.[ContactID] = B.[ContactID])
SELECT  T1.ContactID
       ,T1.EmployeeID
       ,T2.AddressID
FROM    T1
INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[EmployeeAddress] T2
ON      T1.EmployeeID = T2.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up figuring it out after a few hours yesterday, but got so wrapped up in my work. This is exactly what I ended up doing though! :-)